# Trying to get the output of time command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

When I run the below command on the terminal it's working fine.

```
$ var=`(time  mysqldump -v -u'user' -p'password' database > db-backup.sql 2> 
/tmp/mysqldump-output) 2>&1 | grep real | awk  '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d"m"`
$ echo $var
0
```

**But when I use same command in the bash script it's not working properly**

Below is script:

```
$ cat db-backup.sh
#!/bin/bash
var=`(time  mysqldump -v -u'user' -p'password' database > database-backup.sql 2> /tmp/mysqldump-output) 2>&1 | grep real | awk  '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d"m"`
echo $var
```

script output:

```
$ sh -x db-backup.sh
+ grep real
+ awk {print $2}
+ cut -f1 -dm
+ var=
+ echo
```

Comment: Backticks \` are discouraged. Please use `$( .. )` `its not working properly` - how do you detect that? What does that mean? Please be more specific, concentrate on facts, not intepretation. `Not able to understand the issue.` -> [How to debug bash scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155570/209955). Please add `set -x` to the beginning of the script and show it's execution.

Comment: I have updated the more details

Comment: You are running your script with `sh`, it's not `bash`. It looks like your `time` is not printing anything. It looks like `mysqldump` is not even running, you should have seen `+ mysqldump ...` line (or you removed it, that's good!). Try a different command, so that others can reproduce the problem? Ex. something like `var=$((time sleep 1) 2>&1  | grep real | awk  '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d"m")`? - It works for me. Maybe add `tee /dev/stderr` between, like `(time mysqldump.....) | tee /dev/stderr | grep ...` and observe the output.

Comment: Try using `/usr/bin/time` otherwise you'll be using bash's builtin `time` function. There's much more functionality in the standalone time utility.

Comment: All this ```| grep real | awk  '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d"m"```can be replaced by ```| awk '/real/{split($2, a, "m"); print a[1]}'```.

Comment: A nice feature of the external time utility, is you can specify a format string to get exactly the value you need. This can save lots of parsing.

Comment: With GNU time: `/usr/bin/time -f '%e' sleep 1` Output: `1.00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the script with bash it worked.

```
$ bash -x  db-backup.sh
++ grep real
++ awk '{print $2}'
++ cut -f1 -dm
+ var=0
+ echo 0
0
```